# Combinatorial identity using number of ways through the grid

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I'm stuck on this problem and I feel very stupid about it. It goes like this:

Let $k, n$ be natural numbers such that $k < n/2$. Find the injection from the set of all possible ways to go from $(0,0)$ to $(k, n-k)$ (any way to go is a combination of steps right $(x+1,y)$ and up $(x, y+1)$) to the set of ways to go from $(0,0)$ to $(k+1, n-k-1)$.

I'm pretty certain it exists, since from the Pascal Triangle is apparent that $nCk \le nC(k+1)$ for $k < n/2$. I just don't know how to construct it.

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Hint: reflection principle. Reflect the path at the first time it hits a certain line.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was very helpgul